# It's possible to translate SQL to ElasticSearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I need some help. I've few MySQL queries and I need to "translate" it into ElasticSearch syntax.

There are different kind of querys, easy "selects", and others with Join's that I think it's not possible to translate it.

What is best thing I can do?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing I can recommend is read up about ElasticSearch and rethink the whole thing. Usually when modelling data for a search engine/NOSQL is not the same as modelling it for a RDB. Understanding the concept is my best advice here. No quick fix.

Books and sources I recommend.

[ElasticSearch Server](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518440)

[NoSQL Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321826620)

[ElasticSearch.org](http://elasticsearch.org)

Hope that helps you on the way. But like I said no real quick fix or translation table to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL data mapping to ElasticSearch can be done easily with:

1.Proper Data Modelling by de-normalization based on your query requirements
2.If still want have relationships without re-indexing then Parent-Child Realtionship
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Thanks,
Vishu